# vega-lite: how to add timeFormatLocale to vega editor?

Tags: vega-lite

In [this example](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQspAjhoQmAE5xBwiAH0mSLYLgBPRSAAmcaFpo5M7eegAqOvTQhXnmM2igmHAAHpgaAJKyZDoQEDQABLRsWirCcA4JNLIJbhlIODRICVHBsvHExQAUbhEAlAnFUHIAZlpymGwJzTkOzaSZnZhIwlk5tVbNgikaAMQAjABsABwAwqsA7FYtHQDKNABe6qjzy0pIsrAz6BDDWuFKO7Lh6ACyHRAZWkgPIBDMfgC6AAMilEFk8AwEAlrGxploEvFMI01JgFN05J8oMFMAwEUhrI5vFBsmQEro6JQEgA5VQY2SVLwQcmyGjQpBQBJtUk0PTFFpwBi0H5Wf5MQFwABiHQ072eny033CAF8lNYfihUKA8YINFhcPgiLRbtQ6IwmAwFT0yphKM0EAQkEwUlpLRwNi0AMzLMQABiYy2sTA2ABZrABORYAJnmUZDTBDnpDcHmTBaSF9cGjBG%20AHcCNYo1GxFmg1AWjGmFHrJ6oKc4NZ5r75khPUw4GIOXBPWJliGkGIxNYCNpdPoDAgEAYVAc7RBiCBVZpvuUdloEGgANqgKAjKAMQQ-Y42H5QyhqT4AagA5Alr5fnGppeuflV1biEJR30h0deAKQAELXnUVhID4bwdDAi4ALpKMgWgANYaDgbDZL88A0GQWBoCGvq%20kouY0NY9A4XhShwJcbCEtEgQgCEtEtDQujWBopKxPEBjBN8hRIAYaEURUvGTr45g4MeACODAXH4Pw0KQvh0ECIBRDEdjxEk7CpCMTGZNkuQRKKu5AqARztGg6aCJ8Sg4AS1FkGgTbKkulhaiAjHMRoXEFEUfHPAJclCRuSiYKJElSc8dCyfJwWKcebhsMMZgJH0bADIkekTEo0AjMcJkZGw5kjFZIA2dYdkOb6TnBWwcLODgW6gO5ggseg34iWJnmICh3y6jF-jHhe6iPCkyAvCAgGLgojVMc1GhtcFoWdQg3UjAp-VzRqMFKFM1zTR5EHPFBC0degshsAg2SrUoZhkBRLVBLFsp2DQk1-EZuVvdwx7DEwZhIAwTaLlVICxHC8mudlxl0axsi2GJsMUb8LkgNkcN3YjQPKkAA) I have a date field, and I use it for tooltips and legend.

I would like to have it Italian. I know I can add `timeFormatLocale` config, but how to use it in the editor?

```json
timeFormatLocale: {
        "dateTime": "%A %e %B %Y, %X",
        "date": "%d/%m/%Y",
        "time": "%H:%M:%S",
        "periods": ["AM", "PM"],
        "days": ["Domenica", "Lunedì", "Martedì", "Mercoledì", "Giovedì", "Venerdì", "Sabato"],
        "shortDays": ["Dom", "Lun", "Mar", "Mer", "Gio", "Ven", "Sab"],
        "months": ["Gennaio", "Febbraio", "Marzo", "Aprile", "Maggio", "Giugno", "Luglio", "Agosto", "Settembre", "Ottobre", "Novembre", "Dicembre"],
        "shortMonths": ["Gen", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Mag", "Giu", "Lug", "Ago", "Set", "Ott", "Nov", "Dic"]
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide a `config` config having `locale` and add your timeFormatLocale in `time` as done below or in [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega-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-yQMhkmPGghVkICQDrMhhAQ60yDYW4EN2OBsEQb91CUAB5bA2HwqxqTYUgEDIpQyxoKA8J0G9l1XOV6EfZ8LxAD9rwgo9gNA-ctQHWDd2EzN0KsbDfmI34KOIKw6KgRdlVUosfhQVBQDxQQNCwXB8CIWhbmoOhGCYBgFR6MpMEoZogznFItEsjgNhaABmZYxAABiYZZrCYDYABZrAATkWAAmeYIqCpggvcoK4HmJgWiQby4EighvgAdwIawIoisQMoCqAWiipgIusdyoFORt5m8%20YkHcpg4DEDk4HcsRliCpAxDEf1tF0fQDAQBADBUA47IgBTVU0b5yh2LQEC3UA9UEKAGEEX10B9XEEEoNRPgAagAcgSE6jucNRpSWn4ql2qFKF2pB0ROy1HROuorCQVMQDYmAQGVJdkC0ABrDQcDYbJfngTUsDQILvO8pRspoax6ARpGlAnZpCWibUQm1DVdGsDRSVieIDGCb5CiQAxoYnCo6dG3xzETDQAEcGAuPwfhoUhQ38Y4QCiGI7HiJJ2FSEYaCTMZcgiUU1uNI52jQVLBE%20JQcAJPGtROby1JASwtJAYnBFJ9BqYKIp6eeRn%20eZ5alEwNnha5nm6D5gWXboIEQDcNhhjMBI%20kouXsgVpX9W1VXT1QDWtZAHXrD1tB6qNzo4WcHAVrN2WLY0Z7WfZq3EEh75dN9oWNEOgizZSZAXhAd7AYUUBzctk1hhL4XggQCuRkF-3i6BtU4WuDuC67-7e40eCEGyIelDMMgJ0tw0a7eOwaDbv5le1LhED7uczCQBh6sBo3YjhAXTegGPTcJ9BslsRNZFsZ4rBNkBX7gd-P4qlUkAA).

```
"config": {
    "locale": {
      "time": {
        "dateTime": "%A %e %B %Y, %X",
        "date": "%d/%m/%Y",
        "time": "%H:%M:%S",
        "periods": ["AM", "PM"],
        "days": [
          "Domenica",
          "Lunedì",
          "Martedì",
          "Mercoledì",
          "Giovedì",
          "Venerdì",
          "Sabato"
        ],
        "shortDays": ["Dom", "Lun", "Mar", "Mer", "Gio", "Ven", "Sab"],
        "months": [
          "Gennaio",
          "Febbraio",
          "Marzo",
          "Aprile",
          "Maggio",
          "Giugno",
          "Luglio",
          "Agosto",
          "Settembre",
          "Ottobre",
          "Novembre",
          "Dicembre"
        ],
        "shortMonths": [
          "Gen",
          "Feb",
          "Mar",
          "Apr",
          "Mag",
          "Giu",
          "Lug",
          "Ago",
          "Set",
          "Ott",
          "Nov",
          "Dic"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
```